# Any way to Speed up OS X Screen Sharing

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

For a fair amount of time I used to use LogMeIn for remote logging in but their prices are becoming to expensive lately with the Canadian dollar for it to be worth it for me.

So I decided to give the built in Screen Sharing a try. It was a quick setup and am accessing it remotely from a Windows machine using VNC viewer but my internet connection appears to be a huge bottle neck.

In VNC Viewer I only have a few options for quality, it is currently set to 'Best Compression' (8 colors) and I could do with much worse quality.

With Logmein It was possible to go even further with black/white, which would be fine with me as well. Is there any way to do this with the built in Screen sharing?

Any other suggestions to speed up the experience?

EDIT - Specs:

- 15in rMBP(2013?) running OS X Sierra
- Using VNC Viewer on Windows 7 to access it

Comment: Please add what version of VNC Viewer and Windows you are using to your question.

Comment: @tubedogg Done! Sorry about that

Comment: You can set it lower on your VNC client. If your current client doesn't allow that, try a different one.